# This site can't be reached DNS couldn't be found

Tags: apache, manjaro

Why do I get DNS error what is wrong with my configurations???

browser when I head to http://syscape.localhost.com/:

```
This site can’t be reachedsyscape.localhost.com’s DNS address could not be found. Diagnosing the problem.
DNS_PROBE_POSSIBLE
```

/etc/hosts:

```
# Host addresses
127.0.0.1  localhost
127.0.1.1  ahmed-x550la
::1        localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1    ip6-allnodes
ff02::2    ip6-allrouters
12.34.56.789  syscape.localhost
```

//etc/httpd/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
<virtualhost *:80="">
    ServerAdmin webmaster@syscape.localhost.com
    DocumentRoot "/mnt/01D645410BD5F390/www/syscape.localhost"
    ServerName syscape.localhost
    ServerAlias www.syscape.localhost.com
    ErrorLog "logs/syscape.localhost.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/syscape.localhost.com-access.log" common
</virtualhost>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Note the difference between your definition `syscape.localhost` and the URL `syscape.localhost.com`. They're not the same

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are working in a development environment.  You need to add the `subdomain` AND the `.com` to your `hosts` file.  Your machine is going out to the internet, looking at DNS servers to obtain that addresses location, and getting nothing, because, in fact, it doesn't exist out there.  So make your network settings look at your development machine ...

If you are in Windows, That is located at

```
C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

It's easiest to open Notepad (Open as Administrator).

If you have Linux or Mac, it's located at:

```
/etc/hosts
```

You can use VIM or NANO, whatever you're comfy with.

One you are editing the file, you need to add the line:

```
12.34.56.789        syscape.localhost.com
# IF THIS IS YOUR LOCAL MACHINE ..  YOU CAN JUST
127.0.0.1           syscape.localhost.com
```

**ALSO**

In your `VirtualHosts` file .. You need to change:

```
 ServerName syscape.localhost
```

To

```
 ServerName syscape.localhost.com
```